Cron Job Scheduled on cPanel Not Executing PHP Script at the Specified Time but on test runs only
I have a cron job set up on cPanel to run a PHP API daily at midnight (German timezone). The script checks an API and generates recurring tasks, but it’s not executing correctly at the scheduled time.
Current Setup:
Cron job configuration 1:
/usr/bin/curl -s https://clients_domain/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php

Cron job configuration 2:
/usr/bin/php82 /usr/www/users/user_name/maintenance/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php

Manually triggering the API works fine, and I can confirm that the script behaves as expected when called directly. The cron logs indicate that the job starts, but tasks aren’t generated. Here’s a log entry when I ran the job manually:
Oct 7 11:10:01 www390 CRON[32665]: (user_name) CMD ('/usr/bin/flock' -n -E 0 '/usr/home/user_name/.tmp/bdc369237527a953f28e2870e706903f.lck' '/bin/bash' -c '/usr/bin/php82 /usr/www/users/user_name/maintenance/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php schedule:run >> /dev/null 2>&1')

After realizing I was calling the API, which requires a GET request, I switched to this:
/usr/bin/curl -s https://clients_domain/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php >> /usr/home/user_name/cron.log 2>&1

Here’s a log from a successful manual trigger:
{"status":200,"message":"No recurring tasks to create"}

However, when scheduled, it’s not running properly at the specified time. Logs from the client showed the cron ran but didn’t execute the tasks as intended:
Oct 8 08:43:01 www390 CRON[72554]: (user_name) CMD ('/usr/bin/flock' -n -E 0 '/usr/home/user_name/.tmp/f0c00bd5f7b9f9e68ac1edc278927e6e.lck' '/bin/bash' -c '/usr/bin/curl "https://clients_domain/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php >> /usr/home/user_name/cron.log 2>&1"')

When I asked the client to use the following command:
/usr/bin/curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://clients_domain/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php >> /home/user_name/cron.log 2>&1

They updated the cron job to:
01 00 * * * /usr/bin/curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET "https://clients_domain/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php" >> /home/user_name/cron.log 2>&1

Despite this change, the cron job is still not executing as expected at the scheduled time. The cron logs show that it ran only when scheduled manually, not at midnight as intended.
Here’s what I saw in my custom logs when I triggered the job manually:
========================================
[09-10-2024 08:07:17] [INFO] CRON Job: Check and Recreate Recurring Tasks - (Started)
[09-10-2024 08:07:17] [INFO] Task check and recreation response: {"status":201,"message":"Recurring tasks created successfully","task_recreated":2}
[09-10-2024 08:07:17] [INFO] CRON Job: Check and Recreate Recurring Tasks - (Completed) in 0.064024925231934 seconds
========================================

THis is the file im calling the api:
<?php
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

$logFile = __DIR__ . '/../../cron_log.txt';

function logMessage($message, $type = 'INFO')
{
    global $logFile;
    $timestamp = date("d-m-Y H:i:s");
    $ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'] ?? 'CLI';

    if ($message === "========================================") {
        $logEntry = "========================================" . PHP_EOL . PHP_EOL;
    } else {
        $logEntry = "[$timestamp] [$type] [IP: $ipAddress] $message" . PHP_EOL;
    }

    file_put_contents($logFile, $logEntry, FILE_APPEND);
}

header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Content-Type: application/json");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: Access-Control-Allow-Headers, Content-Type, Access-Control-Allow-Methods, Authorization, X-Requested-With");

$startTime = microtime(true);
logMessage("========================================", 'INFO');
logMessage("CRON Job: Check and Recreate Recurring Tasks - (Started)", 'INFO');

$request_method = $_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"];
logMessage("Request Method: $request_method", 'INFO');

if ($request_method == "GET") {
    require_once "../config/database.php";
    require_once "../models/TaskAssignment.php";

    $database = new Database();
    $db = $database->connectDB();
    logMessage("Database connection established", 'INFO');

    $task_assignment = new TaskAssignment($db);

    try {
        $response = $task_assignment->checkAndRecreateRecurringTasks();
        logMessage("Task check and recreation response: " . json_encode($response), 'INFO');

        if ($response["status"] == 201) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 201 Created");
            echo json_encode(array("status" => 201, "message" => "Wiederkehrende Aufgaben erfolgreich erstellt", "task_recreated" => $response["task_recreated"]));
            logMessage("Recurring tasks successfully created", 'INFO');
        } else if ($response["status"] == 200) {
            header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
            echo json_encode(array("status" => 200, "message" => "Keine wiederkehrenden Aufgaben zu erstellen"));
            logMessage("No recurring tasks to create", 'INFO');
        } else {
            header("HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error");
            echo json_encode(array("status" => 500, "message" => "Interner Serverfehler"));
            logMessage("Internal server error", 'ERROR');
        }
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        header("HTTP/1.1 503 Service Unavailable");
        echo json_encode(array("status" => 503, "message" => "Aufgaben konnten nicht überprüft und aktualisiert werden"));
        logMessage("Exception occurred: " . $e->getMessage(), 'ERROR');
    }
} else {
    header("HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed");
    echo json_encode(array("status" => 405, "message" => "Methode nicht erlaubt"));
    logMessage("Method not allowed: $request_method", 'WARNING');
}

$endTime = microtime(true);
$executionTime = $endTime - $startTime;
logMessage("CRON Job: Check and Recreate Recurring Tasks - (Completed) in $executionTime seconds", 'INFO');
logMessage("========================================", 'INFO');


What I Tried:

Initially, I set up the cron job using this command:
/usr/bin/curl -s https://clients_domain/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php

This was supposed to call the API, but it didn’t work as expected.

I then tried another approach using PHP directly:
/usr/bin/php82 /usr/www/users/user_name/maintenance/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php

But still, the tasks weren’t generated.

After realizing the API required a GET request, I modified the cron job to:
/usr/bin/curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://clients_domain/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php >> /usr/home/user_name/cron.log 2>&1

This worked manually but didn't execute at the scheduled time. I later asked the client to set the cron job with this configuration to run at 00:01 daily:
01 00 * * * /usr/bin/curl -H "Content-Type: application/json" -X GET https://clients_domain/api/task_assignments/checkAndRecur.php >> /home/user_name/cron.log 2>&1



What I Expected:
I expected the cron job to execute automatically at the scheduled time (00:01 every day) and trigger the API, which should then check for and generate recurring tasks. The tasks should be created as shown in my manual tests, where the API returned a success message.

Really hard to tell here, whether this is about an issue with your script, or your client simply can't manage to set up the cron as expected. "After realizing the API required a GET request, I modified the cron job to" - what does the method of the API call within your script, have to do with how your script is getting triggered?

Is this a problem with cron itself, or with an kind of API?

It worked when i was hitting my api file with curl it was throwing the error now i performed the same functionality inside a php script without checking for headers and requests, that i was performing in the api and setup the cron by using the exact path to the php script, i think the issue was because i was sending the req to the api using the URL like the domain,,,,
